# Convert XLD to Region

Tags: type-conversion, region, halcon

I'm using this code to convert a XLD to a region:

```
 gen_region_contour_xld (ConnectedDirtRegionsXLDWorld,RegionWorld,'filled')
```

the XLD is like this:

[image]

and the resulting region looks like this:

[image]

If we overlap them, we can see that there are some differences, in particular the one marked with the arrow:

[image]

I understand that float values are converted to its nearest integer, so on average I would expect some to be rounded up, and some down and the area to be roughly the same. I cannot understand the differences in this case, since it looks that the values have all been rounded up..

I also tried by using `set_system('neighborhood',4)`, it got a little bit better, but not really much. Also this causes a whole load of problem in the rest of the code, so I have set it back to 8 as it was before.

How can this conversion be made more precisely?

Comment: Hi, please can you add a file with the contours data? You can easily do this using a procedure as write_contour_xld_arc_info or write_contour_xld_dxf.

Comment: Hello! Here it is: http://www.igormasin.it/cont.txt I used the write_contour_xld_arc_info procedure. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please have a look at the following image.

[image]

Here you can see the real dimension of a pixel (the red square).

So space, where you have drawn the arrow, has 1-pixel width!

Comment: thank you very much.. i thought that a pixel was the size of the jagged line..